# MySQL group by query consuming a 20x of disk space

Tags: mysql, group-by, diskspace

I have a table of 40 gb disk space with about 500MM rows. 
I am running a query

```
select col0 , col1, group_concat('(', col2 , ',' , col4 , ')') as 
str from table
group by col0, col1
```

When I run the query, the disk space utilization shoots up by 20x linearly and my node goes out of space.

[image]
What is the reason behind such high disk usage? Maybe, this could be related to how group by works in mysql

What could I do differently in the query to get the data I am looking for?

Comment: There's two things that I might think of, and I don't know which it is. One is the fact that grouping just takes space, especially if you're doing a sequential table scan. One is the fact that by default most client libraries will receive the resultset in bulk. The first thing would be to look at `EXPLAIN`. The second would be to see if streaming the dataset would reduce the disk load (which I'm thinking might be possible if you have a sensible index on `(col0, col1)`). But you have posted no `EXPLAIN`, no schema, and also no client library/language, so.... *shrug*

Answer (score 0):

Mysql creates temporary table for intermediate results.

If you don't care about order of rows in result, adding `ORDER BY NULL` improves performance and reduces disk usage signifficantly.

If ORDER BY is not specified, expressions used in GROUP BY are used for ordering,
so `GROUP BY col0, col1` is equivalent to `GROUP BY col0, col1 ORDER BY by col0, col1`

Comment: I'm thinking that if you get a streaming resultset, and there is a covering index for `col0, col1`, chances are good you'd just need to have one group's worth of data in memory, not all groups at once (which you'd have to have with `ORDER BY NULL`). Just a hypothesis, not 100% sure whether MySQL would do this, but that's an obvious optimisation to think of, so I'm reasonably sure cleverer people than me have thought of it.

Comment: no improvement in disk usage after using `ORDER BY NULL`

Comment: @vinit Please add output of EXPLAIN SELECT ... , and CREATE TABLE statement of this table to your question as requested by amadan.